# How to set color area when value less than zero use Apexcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, apexcharts

This is my script options, use apexcharts chart

And my script

```
                var options = {
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Profit',
                        data: [{"x":"2021-08-29","y":0.23},{"x":"2021-08-30","y":-5.29},{"x":"2021-08-31","y":-0.02},{"x":"2021-09-01","y":5.38},...
                    }],
                    chart: {
                        type: 'area',
                        height: 350,
                        zoom: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        toolbar: {
                            show: false
                        }
                    },
                    stroke: {
                        show: true,
                        curve: 'smooth',
                        lineCap: 'butt',
                        width: 2
                    },
                    fill: {
                        type: 'gradient',
                        gradient: {
                            shadeIntensity: 1,
                            opacityFrom: 0.45,
                            opacityTo: 0.9
                        },
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        area: {
                            colors: {
                                ranges: [
                                    {
                                        from: -100,
                                        to: 0,
                                        color: "#e85347" // Red color
                                    },
                                    {
                                        from: 0,
                                        to: 100,
                                        color: "#1ee0ac" // Green color
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            columnWidth: "80%"
                        }
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        labels: {
                            offsetX: 0,
                        },
                        axisBorder: {
                            show: false,
                        },
                        axisTicks: {
                            show: false
                        }
                    },
                    xaxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        tickAmount: 8,
                        labels: {
                            rotate: -45,
                            rotateAlways: true,
                            formatter: function(val, timestamp) {
                                return moment(new Date(timestamp)).format("DD MMM")
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        shared: true
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: 'top',
                        horizontalAlign: 'right',
                        offsetX: -10
                    }
                };

                var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#portfolio_line"), options);
                chart.render();
```

How to config when value less than zero so bar color will is Red color, and greater than 0 will is Green color

[image]

Comment: From what I've seen in the docs, it doesn't seem like this is supported. Did you end up solving it? Was there another chart library that you used to achieve this?

Comment: @CaseyGibson Have you found a solution with apexchart?

Comment: @user109764 I haven't used it since I came across this issue. I ended up changing to a different library due to this. I don't remember what we used instead as I know longer work at that company.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it using a vertical gradient. Where percent is the percentage of the range area graph.

```
fill:{
  opacity:[0.8, 1, 1],
  type: ["fill", 'fill', 'fill'],
  gradient: {
    type:'vertical',
    opacityFrom: 0.6,
    opacityTo: 0.6,
    gradientToColors:['#4d2e54'],
    stops: [0,0, percent,percent,  100]
  }
},
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Could you add a reproducible example?

Comment: @adelriosantiago Hello. Have you found a solution with apexchart? When I tried the above it's mulicolor, but with gradient transition..

Answer (score 0):

Following Prakhar suggestion, I have achieved similar with this:

```
  colors: ['#B72136'], // red
  fill: {
    type: "gradient",

    gradient: {
      type: 'vertical',
      //shadeIntensity: 0,
      //opacityFrom: 1,
      //opacityTo: 1,
      gradientToColors:['#007B55'], // green
      stops: [50, 0],
```

https://codepen.io/webxtor/pen/ZEmgMMV

**EDIT:** I have achieved to remove gradient feature by settings stops to 50,0

Answer (score 0):

To configure the ApexCharts chart so that values less than zero are represented with red bars and values greater than zero are represented with green bars, you need to modify the `plotOptions` section in your `options` object. Specifically, you should define two separate ranges in the `colors` section within the `plotOptions` for the `area` chart type. Here's how you can modify your existing `options` object:

```js
var options = {
    // ... your existing options ...

    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            colors: {
                ranges: [
                    {
                        from: -Infinity, // Any value less than this will be red
                        to: 0,
                        color: "#e85347" // Red color
                    },
                    {
                        from: 0,
                        to: Infinity, // Any value greater than this will be green
                        color: "#1ee0ac" // Green color
                    }
                ]
            },
            columnWidth: "80%"
        }
    },

    // ... rest of your existing options ...
};
```

In this modified version of your `options` object, the `ranges` array in the `colors` section of the `plotOptions` now defines two ranges:

1. Values less than zero will be colored red (`"#e85347"`).
2. Values greater than or equal to zero will be colored green (`"#1ee0ac"`).

With this configuration, the chart bars will be colored according to your specified conditions.